# How get original object of Menu Item, bound to List

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have list of objects *MyList* with Name and ID properties.
I also have XAML:

```
<MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding MyList, Converter={StaticResource MyConv}} Click="MyMethod">
```

Data converter *MyConv* converts objects in the *MyList* to list of strings, based on objects properties, e.g. Name and ID.

I need get original object in *MyMethod*, but if I handle click event, this code prints "System.String[]":

```
Private Sub MyMethod(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim mnuItm as MenuItem = DirectCast(sender, MenuItem)
    Debug.WriteLine(mnuItm.ItemsSource.GetType)
End Sub
```

How can I get original object, that was bound to clicked menu item?

Comment: Cast `mnuItm.DataContext` to the view model type, then access its `MyList` property. However, better bind the MenuItem's Command property to an ICommand in your view model.

Comment: @Clemens No, data context of all controls is MainWindow.

Comment: Ok, you know better than me. Go ahead.

Comment: use command not click event

Comment: @Bijan yes, You're right. But app was wrote, app is big, and I can not change it now. I need add some small functions to extend the app.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get original object, that was bound to clicked menu item?

You can't get it from the `ItemsSource` property of the `MenuItem`.

But, as @Clemens points out in his comment, you should be able to cast the `DataContext` of the `MenuItem` to whatever type where the `MyList` property is defined is and access the original collection, e.g.:

```
Private Sub MyMethod(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim mnuItm as MenuItem = DirectCast(sender, MenuItem)
    Dim dataContext = DirectCast(mnuItm, MainWindow) '<-- change MainWindow to the name of the class where the MyList property is defined
    Dim org = dataContext.Items
End Sub
```